# TypeError: conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, decimal

Any ideas on how to convert a series (column) from float to decimal? I am on Python 3.6. I have read the Decimal documentation, but it offers no help.

```
df['rate'].dtype
Out[158]: dtype('float64')
Decimal(df['rate'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython
   \core\interactiveshell.py", line 2862, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "<ipython-input-159-88710e11f7cd>", line 1, in <module>
    Decimal(df['rate'])
 TypeError: conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't cast like this, you will need to do

```
df['rate'] = df['rate'].apply(Decimal)
```

`pandas` does support `Decimal` but you can't cast like that

Example:

```
In[28]:
from decimal import *
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(Decimal)
df

Out[28]: 
                                                   a         b         c
0  -1.6122557830197199457700207858579233288764953... -1.865243 -0.836893
1  0.96962430214434858211092205237946473062038421... -0.105823 -0.842267
2  -0.9113389075755260471112251252634450793266296... -0.351389 -0.183489
3  1.22765470106414120721183280693367123603820800... -1.232627 -0.067909
4  -0.0376339704393285762185072940155805554240942... -0.445606 -0.080623
```

the dtype will still show `object` but the dtype really is `Decimal`:

```
In[29]:
type(df['a'].iloc[0])

Out[29]: decimal.Decimal
```

If you use `astype(Decimal)` it will look like it worked but it doesn't:

```
In[38]:
df['b'].astype(Decimal)

Out[38]: 
0    -1.86524
1   -0.105823
2   -0.351389
3    -1.23263
4   -0.445606
Name: b, dtype: object
```

If we try to assign this back:

```
In[39]:
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(Decimal)
type(df['b'].iloc[0])

Out[39]: float
```

As pointed out by @JonClements and I agree it is ill-advised to use non-native numpy types as you lose any vectorisation in particular with arithmetic operations, additionally the dtype may be converted when you perform some operation on it which then loses your original intention

Comment: Depending what the OP wants to do this for - creating a `Decimal` from a `float` may well be a waste of time - could well be the thing trying to be avoided has already happened by that point. Underlying manipulation is going to be expensive and not optimised as for specific types by the underlying arrays etc...

Comment: @JonClements true but for some reason this sort of question does pop up from time to time, I'd always advise against not using the native numpy types

Comment: Oh definitely, but if a `Decimal` is really desired and required it's best to get it at the stage of input (maybe using `converters={...}` or whatever), not think it's going to be a magic bullet when you've already been playing with floats :)